# can i use read_excel to import a csv file into r instead of using read.csv?

Tags: r

I was told to use read_excel to import CSV file instead of read.csv, but it is giving me an error

"Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx"

Comment: Why? If the file is already a csv why not use 'read.csv'

Comment: Are you sure you weren't told to use `read_csv` (note the `_`, not the `.`)?

Comment: Yes I am sure and I was confused, I asked a r programmer to help with some work, and they used read_excel instead of read.csv and they insisted on it.  They included "in" after the file name.  Not sure what that does.  But I'll change it to read.csv after he turns his back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use read_csv (importing data as a tibble) or read.csv (importing data as a dataframe) for a csv file. Or you can save your CSV file as an excel file, then use read_excel.